# Performance Image.SCALE_DEFAULT vs Image.SCALE_SMOOTH

Tags: java, multithreading, image, scale, bufferedimage

I scale images in multithreading java program.

I use 2 different methods of scaling:

**1 case:**

```
Image tmp = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(w, h, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

This method loads CPU on 100%. Works 20 seconds on my dataset.

**2 case:**

```
Image tmp = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(w, h, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

This method loads CPU only 50%. 
Works 35 seconds on my dataset.
No matter how much threads running this code.

Feeling like Image.SCALE_SMOOTH uses HDD and it is bottleneck. 
Or uses some queue that not accepts big number of images.

How to improve 2 case performance and use 100% of CPU?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of articles on the www why `.getScaledInstance()` is **evil**

Although I'm not sure if the Java guys didn't fix it under the hood, I recommend you read

[The Perils of `Image.getScaledInstance()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20080516181120/http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

and check the methods described there. There might even be some libraries around that scale much better than jdk default.